# test on files to extract before the output export R

Tags: r, extract, corpus, data-extraction

I have applied some data mining functions of a PDF corpus (541 PDF fie) and i want to save the processed data. 
 I used
       writeCorpus (corpus_processed  )

But I need to add t test on the files to save in fact to save only the files contains the word " America"

I found this  function but i could not proceed the remaining parts to adapt it on my needs. I think also that it is not applicable on a corpus

```
patterns <- sapply(list.files(corpus_processed, full.names=TRUE), FUN=function(x){
  grep("america", readLines(x))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current approach seems to be on the right track, but you are handling the `grep` logic incompletely.  Since `readLines` will return a vector of lines for each file, you need to handle `grep` likely returning a vector of indices.  The definition of a file which matches is that the vector returned from `grep` would not be empty.

```
files <- list.files(corpus_processed, full.names=TRUE)
matches <- sapply(files, function(x) {
    conn <- file(x, open="r")
    count <- length(grep("\\bamerica\\b", readLines(conn)))
    return(count > 0)
})

file_matches <- files[matches]
```

In the code above `matches` should be a boolean vector, which can then be used to subset your original vector of files to obtain those files containing `america`.

**Edit:**

The above script assumes that `files` is a list of files (full paths) which contain your material.  If not, then you will have to provide such a list.

Comment: the function returns this error

Error in list.files(corp, full.names = TRUE) : invalid 'path' argument

I forgot to say that the corpus_processed is a corpus created in the algorithm and it is not a path

Comment: Then convert the corpus to a bona-fide file list.